# Why am i getting this error with this piece of code in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Can you please tell me what I did wrong in this code?

```
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(5):
        print(L[r][c], end=" ")
print()
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
1 2 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#111>", line 3, in <module>
  print(L[r][c], end=" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is L ? Your 2-d array is going out of bounds thats why youre getting that error

Comment: Please include what L is.

Comment: Your first row only contains 2 elements and you are expecting to read 5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently your L array or each sub-array of it doesn't have the dimensions you're supposing they have. This should solve your problem:

```
for r in range(len(L)):
    for c in range(len(L[r])):
        print(L[r][c], end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: This works!!! @olenscki. I just had to indent the last print statement and it runs just fine. I defined L as well.

Comment: @olenscki Why using index when you can use enumeration [as pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62673318/7033655) by KokoEfraim ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do more intuitive and better code, as follow

```
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for row in L:
    for column in row:
        print(column)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration depths are mismatch with your (supposed) nested list. Show us your list L.

Comment: The list L: L = [[1,2,3],
                        [4,5,6],
                        [7,8,9]] @KokoEfraim

Comment: So to avoid index out of range you should set c = 3  and r = 3. Thus your coding should be:

Comment: But I believe olenscki solution above is better: more versatile and error prove for any arbitrary nested list. You should made your question, answered. (You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). Click the green outlined check mark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.)